# Filter Data From MySQLi in other way

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

First of all, I'm a newbie PHP Developer.

I am developing a website which has a database that contains employee records. Each is assigned ID, Name, mobNo, Address etc..

There's a filter panel in the website with many filters to use like name filter, mobNo filter...

What I exactly want is, if 1 filter is selected, PHP will process just 1 MySQLi Query something like:

```
WHERE '$param' LIKE '%$paramValue%'
```

If user selects 2 filters, say Name and mobNo, PHP should process 2 queries something like:

```
WHERE '$param' LIKE '%$paramValue%'AND '$param2' LIKE '%$paramValue2%';
```

Chain should follow on..
I will use AJAX but you need NOT to worry about it.. I will integrate it myself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767026/how-can-i-properly-use-a-pdo-object-for-a-select-query or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422784/multiple-sql-objects-in-php-mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a function like isset() or any other way to check what the user selected, and then display the appropriate query.

i.e.

```
$query = "SELECT blabla WHERE ";
$int = 0; //checks if query needs an 'AND'

    if (isset(filter1)) {
          $query += "$param1 LIKE $paramValue1";
          $int = 1;
    }
    if (isset(filter2)) {
          if ($int = 1)
             $query += " AND ";
          $query += "$param2 LIKE $paramValue2";
          $int = 1;
    }
```

and so on.
Not quite sure that's what you need but hopefully its something like that. Be creative :)

Comment: Bravo..! I couldn't have done it without your help.. Like seriously, salute!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "WHERE '$param' LIKE '%$paramValue%'"; 
if($param2 != '')$sql .= "AND '$param2' LIKE '%$paramValue2%'";
if($param3 != '')$sql .= "AND '$param3' LIKE '%$paramValue3%'";
...
```

if you want the paramenters to be modular you need to add them in pieces depending on wether they are set or not.

Comment: Makes some logic.. If I conbine this idea with another response from Amrito, I'm sure I'll make it work out.. Thanks!!